# What will happen if the user is deleted, while he is connected to MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Suppose there is a MySQL user `alice` that is currently connected to the database. Suppose another user `bob` deletes `alice` while she is still working. What will happen? will `bob` fail? Will `alice` be disconnected immediately? Will she receive error message upon her next query? Or will she be able to finish her session as usual?

Comment: Easy enough to try... fire up two monitor sessions and see what happens.

Comment: i think it can be easily tested by yourself

Comment: @Septagram tell us the result!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[12.7.1.2. DROP USER Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/drop-user.html):

> [`DROP USER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/drop-user.html) does not automatically close any open user sessions. Rather, in the event that a user with an open session is dropped, the statement does not take effect until that user's session is closed. Once the session is closed, the user is dropped, and that user's next attempt to log in will fail. *This is by design*.

...and [5.4.6. When Privilege Changes Take Effect](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privilege-changes.html) it's somehow related:

> If you modify the grant tables indirectly using account-management statements such as `GRANT`, `REVOKE`, or `SET PASSWORD`, the server notices these changes and loads the grant tables into memory again immediately.

Comment: Hm... I did test it and it seems that REVOKE doesn't affect user while he is connected, just as DROP USER doesn't.